# get the updated value of data attr jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var value = $('option:selected', this).val()

  //var sum = parseInt(value);
  if (value < '1') {
    $("#noradiobutton").attr('data-finalvalue', 0);
    $("#input:text").val(0);

  } else {
    console.log(value)
    $('#yesradiobutton').attr('data-finalvalue', value);
    $('#input:text').val(value);
  }


  $('input:text').val(value)

}).change();

$("input:radio[name=yesnoradiobuttongroup]").change(function() {
  var finalvalue;
  if ($("#yesradiobutton").is(':checked')) {
    finalvalue = $(this).data('finalvalue');
    console.log(finalvalue)
    $('input:text').val(finalvalue);
  }
  if ($("#noradiobutton").is(':checked')) {
    finalvalue = $(this).data('finalvalue');
    console.log(finalvalue)
    $('input:text').val(finalvalue);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
  <option value='5'>5</option>
</select>

<input type='text'>
<span><input type="radio" id="yesradiobutton" name="yesnoradiobuttongroup" value="0" class="InputBoxDe" checked/><label for="yesradiobutton">Yes</label></span>
<span><input type="radio" id="noradiobutton" name="yesnoradiobuttongroup" value="1" class="InputBoxDe" /><label for="noradiobutton">No</label></span>
```

I have here select input and radio button. When select is change the value is stored in input and also in radio button as `data attr`. I am getting the first value of `data attr` but I can't get the updated value to show up in input text. But when checking in the dev tools the value in `data attr` is changing.

Question: How to get the latest the value of `data attr`

Scenario: After load select `1` in select option. `1` will be displayed in input and stores in Yes radio button as `data attr`. If you click `No` data in input will be `0` clicking `Yes` will turn it to 1 which is the `data attr`. Selecting `2` in select will dispay `2` in input and also in `data attr` of radio button Yes. Clicking No will again put `0` in input and clicking Yes will display `1` instead of `2` which is the current value of `data attr`.

Requirement: after clicking yes input should display 2 which is the `data attr` of yes button

***[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2hx1xvwg/)***

Comment: You have to use `.on()` to get dynamic changes http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Nisam didnt work check https://jsfiddle.net/2hx1xvwg/1/... radiobutton is not dynamically created.only value is of `data attr` is dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of using `data` use `attr` to read the values

```
  $("input:radio[name=yesnoradiobuttongroup]").change(function () {
        var finalvalue;
        if ($("#yesradiobutton").is(':checked')) {
            finalvalue = $(this).attr("data-finalvalue")
            console.log(finalvalue)
            $('input:text').val(finalvalue);
        }
        if ($("#noradiobutton").is(':checked')) {
            finalvalue = $(this).attr("data-finalvalue")
            console.log(finalvalue)
            $('input:text').val(finalvalue);
        }
 });
```

Comment: Can you please explain the reason @shu? I am curious to know why?

Comment: Can you add explanation I am curious just like @GHOST93.

Comment: @GHOST93 i think it is matter of where the data is stored. when using `attr` to save data it is stored some where and to retrieve it use `attr` when using `data` to save data it is stored some where and to retrieve it use `data`. I may be wrong i will further read doc to completely understand

Comment: @GHOST93 @guradio `data` stores data in key value pair.when you set the `data-finalvalue` using `attr` it will create a key value pair where key is `finalvalue` and value is `selected value`.But when next time when you change the option it did not update the value of `data`.Actually the correct way set the data attribute is `$('#yesradiobutton').data('finalvalue', value)` and then you can read the updated value using `data("data-finalvalue")`

Comment: @shu to get that you need to use `.data(finalvalue)` am i correct? so `data is for data` and `attr is for attr`

Comment: @guradio yes, if you set the `data` using `$('#yesradiobutton').data('finalvalue', value)` you can inspect  the `radio` it will not create any `áttr`. and after that you read the value `$(this).data("finalvalue")`

Comment: @shu Thank you for such a nice explanation! :)